# HP Pavilion 15 pre-installed Ubuntu 12.04 - unable to install Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, live-usb

I have purchased HP Pavilion 15 pre-installed Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) and I want to install Ubuntu 12.10 from a live USB, but it does not install another Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running `do-release-upgrade` from the terminal, so you don't have to bother with live CDs or USBs at all.

Alternatively, you could just reinstall with the newest version of Ubuntu from the CD, by choosing "Erase Ubuntu 12.04 and reinstall." This particular option is a lot easier than using `do-release-upgrade` because you can skip over any updates in between, but definitely not quite as good as updating from the CD by choosing "Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10" from the installation menu.

Of course, be sure to back up all of your important files before updating your version of Ubuntu, in case something goes wrong, no matter which of the above options you choose.